# How to receive a POST, using C#, without knowing the content and throw int to a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So, I configured an external (3rd party) service to send me data through push requests. There aren't many documentation on the format of this data, they just say to point for a URL that accepts POST.

So, I want to capture this message and add to a variable that I can add to a temporary database, and analyse it to create a proper treatment later.

All examples I saw show how to send and capture the response, but I just want to capture a random message that I don't know.

Any Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the format of the request they send to your application, everything will be contained within [the `HttpRequest` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) (which, if you're just talking about a `Page` or something similar, would/should be built-in as the `.Request` property of that page).

If the request has form values, the `.FormData` property on that object will be a `NameValueCollection` of those values.  If it has something in the POST body, the `.InputStream` property on that object will contain that data.  Files, headers, query string values, etc. will all be on that object.

You can copy whatever you like from that object into your data, inspect what you get, tinker to more specifically target the values they send you, etc.  Without knowing the format of the data they're going to send you, anything more specific will require inspecting what they send you and reverse-engineering its format from there.  But all the data will be in that `HttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputStream property of the Request object.  This will give you the raw data of the HTTP request.

```
if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        var wholeRequest = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

If you just want the request body, you can use Request.Form.ToString().

```
if (Request.RequestType == "POST") 
{
    var wholeForm = Request.Form.ToString();
}
```

I would not use the .FormData NameValueCollection unless you know they will be using a content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data.  Other content types will not properly populate that collection.